# Eog how to control delay between slides in a slideshow from command line?

Tags: eog

```
eog --fullscreen --slide-show $ORDNER1/out/
```

In have in my /out folder animated GIF files and I'd like to show all files as a slide show. EOG has a fix time between slides but my animations are longer. EOG cut the animation in the middle an start the next one. How can I can control delay between slides in a slideshow from command line?

Answer (score 8):

EOG has 5 seconds time delay between the slides in fullscreen mode. This parameter can be edited with `dconf`, schema name: `org.gnome.eog.fullscreen`, key `seconds`. Or using `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.eog.fullscreen seconds N
```

where `N` is new interval. `0` disables automatic browsing.
Also the same settings can be adjusted in EOG menu, in Edit > Preferences | Slideshow.

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 16 (?) but not Ubuntu 22.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat That's strange. Ubuntu 22.04.1 with Gnome has got `org.gnome.eog.fullscreen seconds 5` key, the same as in previous versions. Which flavor do you use? Maybe other flavor have this key moved to other schema? Try `gsettings list-recursively | grep eog`, it will show where EOG settings are stored in your system.